# C# native call C++ Dll wglMakeCurrent

Tags: c#, c++, opengl

I'm trying to call wglMakeCurrent using C# native call [DllImport] attribute. The function works and set my opengl context as current.

The thing is sometimes it throws error. It has no pattern, it just fails to make the context current.

I reproduced the same code in c++ and it doesnt have that problem.

My first idea is that it's something related to being HDC or HGLRC handle is not properly disposed or something still keeps alive the handles but I have implemented a cleanup procedure when window is closing I both release HDC and delete HGLRC. In the and it does not work.
Here its the code

```
public enum PixelFormatDescriptorFlags : uint
    {
             PFD_MAIN_PLANE               = 0,
             PFD_OVERLAY_PLANE            = 1,
             PFD_TYPE_RGBA                = 0,
             PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX          = 1,
             PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER             = 0x00000001,
             PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW           = 0x00000004,
             PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP           = 0x00000008,
             PFD_SUPPORT_GDI              = 0x00000010,
             PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL           = 0x00000020,
             PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT           = 0x00000040,
             PFD_NEED_PALETTE             = 0x00000080,
             PFD_NEED_SYSTEM_PALETTE      = 0x00000100,
             PFD_SWAP_EXCHANGE            = 0x00000200,
             PFD_SWAP_COPY                = 0x00000400,
             PFD_SWAP_LAYER_BUFFERS       = 0x00000800,
             PFD_GENERIC_ACCELERATED      = 0x00001000,
             PFD_SUPPORT_DIRECTDRAW       = 0x00002000,
             PFD_DIRECT3D_ACCELERATED     = 0x00004000,
             PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION      = 0x00008000,
             PFD_DEPTH_DONTCARE           = 0x20000000,
             PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER_DONTCARE    = 0x40000000,
             PFD_STEREO_DONTCARE          = 0x80000000
    }

public struct HGLRC
{
    public int Hglrc;
}

public struct PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR
{
    public ushort nSize;
    public ushort nVersion;
    public UInt32 dwFlags;
    public byte iPixelType;
    public byte cColorBits;
    public byte cRedBits;
    public byte cRedShift;
    public byte cGreenBits;
    public byte cGreenShift;
    public byte cBlueBits;
    public byte cBlueShift;
    public byte cAlphaBits;
    public byte cAlphaShift;
    public byte cAccumBits;
    public byte cAccumRedBits;
    public byte cAccumGreenBits;
    public byte cAccumBlueBits;
    public byte cAccumAlphaBits;
    public byte cDepthBits;
    public byte cStencilBits;
    public byte cAuxBuffers;
    public byte iLayerType;
    public byte bReserved;
    public UInt32 dwLayerMask;
    public UInt32 dwVisibleMask;
    public UInt32 dwDamageMask;
}

public static class Win32GL
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ZeroGDIInterface.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int ChoosePixelFormatGDI(Win32HDC hdc,ref PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR desc);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ZeroGDIInterface.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SetPixelFormatGDI(Win32HDC hdc,int format, ref PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR desc);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ZeroGDIInterface.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern HGLRC wglCreateContextGDI(Win32HDC hdc);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ZeroGDIInterface.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int wglMakeCurrentGDI(Win32HDC hdc,HGLRC hglrc);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ZeroGDIInterface.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int wglDeleteContextGDI(HGLRC hglrc);
}
        WindowsWindow win32Window = ownerWindow as WindowsWindow;

        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = new PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR();
        pfd.nSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf<PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR>();
        pfd.dwFlags = (uint)(PixelFormatDescriptorFlags.PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PixelFormatDescriptorFlags.PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PixelFormatDescriptorFlags.PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER);
        pfd.iPixelType = (byte)PixelFormatDescriptorFlags.PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
        pfd.nVersion = 1;
        pfd.cColorBits = 32;
        pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;
        pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
        pfd.cStencilBits = 8;
        pfd.iLayerType = (byte)PixelFormatDescriptorFlags.PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

        int pixelFormat = Win32GL.ChoosePixelFormatGDI(win32Window.Hdc, ref pfd);

        if(pixelFormat == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Choose pixel format failed!");
        }

        if (Win32GL.SetPixelFormatGDI(win32Window.Hdc, pixelFormat, ref pfd) == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Set pixel format failed!");
        }

        HGLRC dummyContext = Win32GL.wglCreateContextGDI(win32Window.Hdc);

        if(dummyContext.Hglrc == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create wgl context");
        }

        if (Win32GL.wglMakeCurrentGDI(win32Window.Hdc, dummyContext) == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to make the dummy context current! = ");
        }
```

Edit: When it does not throw error, I can simply use the context for clear color and swapping the swapchain buffers. So native bindings and the code works as intended

Edit: Added the [DllImport] and used structures

Comment: Does it fails erratically the first time you use this code? Or later, when you call `wglMakeCurrentGDI`?

Comment: It "Usually" works upon each rebuild(had occasions that it didnt even run after rebuild), after that it's literally random. Like you said it fails erratically.

Comment: Is your C# code using multiple threads?  Both Win32 windows and OpenGL current context have thread affinity.

Comment: Nope they running on the same thread. I do not use multiple threads

Comment: Can you show your `DllImport` definitions? Also relevant structs and enums. How often are you calling this code, if it's often you need to make sure to release the handles each time. Also instead of `throw new Exception("...` use `throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());` and make sure to specify `SetLastError = true` on your `DllImport`

Comment: I have added the code fragments you requested. I run the context codes per application. So ı only run them when the application initialization begin.